# Correct way to resolve promise after updating state?

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to append items to an array in state synchronously, but only the last item is getting appended. I think this is because state is being read in each "update" call before it is updated--a typical race conditions issue. What is the conventional way to handle this operation? I'm using React Hooks, and setIndepAttributes comes from useState.

```
    async function onFilesAdded(e) {
        ...
    for(var i = 0; i < atts.length; i++) {
        await addAtt(atts[i]);
    }
        ...
```

```
    async function addAtt(att) {
        return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
            await props.addIndependentAttribute(att);
            resolve("done");
        });
    }
```

```
    function addIndependentAttribute(att) {
        return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
            await setIndepAttributes([...indepAttributes, att]);
            resolve("done");
        });
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of your component and how these functions are called from it